# Where is ptrace in linux kernel?

Tags: c, linux-kernel, ptrace

I can't find it in kernel source with `global ptrace`, there is no definition in kernel/ptrace.c like it was stated in man page..... I can see kernel/ptrace.c and include/linux/ptrace.h but there is nothing

Comment: If you mean the system call, pretty sure it's defined: https://elixir.bootlin.com/linux/v5.3.1/source/kernel/ptrace.c#L1237

Comment: How am I supposed to find this type of declarations, except reading code and looking for hints like `SYSCALL_DEFINE4`(ptrace...? global doesn't handle this if I just type `global ptrace`

Comment: @MichaelFoukarakis: OP asked for `ptrace()`. It's libc that calls ptrace syscall.

Comment: @M.Kalter i don't know of the limitations of `global`. Other IDEs or cross-reference tools certainly can, and the kernel's conventions for declaring system calls are well-established, but these are not the subject of the question.

Comment: @ArkadiuszDrabczyk I think the question is exceedingly clear.

Comment: @ArkadiuszDrabczyk Honestly I was looking for syscall implementation by kernel. I just didn't think ptrace could be defined in both kernel and glibc. Your answer was useful nevertheless

Comment: @M.Kalter: `ptrace()` is not defined in kernel, it's defined only in libc. There is a syscall implementation in kernel.

Comment: @M.Kalter: it goes like that: `INLINE_SYSCALL` (glibc) -> `INTERNAL_SYSCALL` (glibc) - `__NR_ptrace` in kernel.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You need to look for it in your libc source code, for example
[glibc](https://www.gnu.org/software/libc/) or
[musl](https://www.musl-libc.org).  And notice what does it say in
`man ptrace` under `NOTES` section:

> Although arguments to ptrace() are interpreted according to the
>   prototype given, glibc currently declares ptrace() as a variadic
>   function with only the request argument fixed.  It is recommended to
>   always supply four arguments, even if the requested operation does not
>   use them, setting unused/ignored arguments to 0L or (void *) 0.

In `glibc` for example `ptrace()` is defined in
`sysdeps/unix/sysv/linux/ptrace.c`:

```
long int
ptrace (enum __ptrace_request request, ...)
{
  long int res, ret;
  va_list ap;
  pid_t pid;
  void *addr, *data;

  va_start (ap, request);
  pid = va_arg (ap, pid_t);
  addr = va_arg (ap, void *);
  data = va_arg (ap, void *);
  va_end (ap);

  if (request > 0 && request < 4)
    data = &ret;

  res = INLINE_SYSCALL (ptrace, 4, request, pid, addr, data);
  if (res >= 0 && request > 0 && request < 4)
    {
      __set_errno (0);
      return ret;
    }

  return res;
}
```

Comment: How did you see it was actually part of libc?... ptrace wiki page doesn't mention it; it seems to me I miss something essential

Comment: Manpages usually (I don't want to say *always* because I can never be
sure) describe libc interfaces and often focus on GLIBC
specifically. The intention is that programmers don't have to use kernel
and architecture specific code but would use unified libc
interface. GLIBC is ported to multiple architectures and systems but
code of the userland program doesn't have to change.